# SVM : support vector has margin of 0?

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, scikit-learn

I am trying to generate the separating hyperplane of binary classification for 3D points.

Here are my points, which are linearly separable.

```
Class 0: [[0,0,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [0.5,0.4,0.4]]
Class 1: [[1,3,1], [2,0,2], [1,1,1]]
```

From `sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='linear')`, the following is produced:

```
w = clf.coeff_ = [ 1.   0.5  0.5]
b = clf.intercept_ = -2.0
sv = clf.support_vectors_ = 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

The understanding is, if `w.dot(x)+b` returns a negative value, then x is of Class 0; if positive value, then Class 1. However, `w.dot([1,1,1])+b = 0` !! This means that `[1,1,1]`, which is a **support vector** from Class 1, **lies** on the separating plane..... while no SVs from Class 0 lie on the sep. plane.

**SO MY QUESTION IS...**

My data is linearly separable, so theoretically an SVM should have margins >0 for both classes. But here, my SVM has a =0 for class1 and >0 margin for class0. Why is this the case? And if my hyperplane is incorrect, how can I calculate the correct hyperplane? Thank you.

**CODE**

```
from sklearn import svm
X0 = [[0,0,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [0.5,0.4,0.4]]
Y0 = [0] * len(X0)
X1 = [[1,3,1], [2,0,2], [1,1,1]]
Y1 = [1] * len(X1)
X = X0 + X1
Y = Y0 + Y1
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, Y)
sv = clf.support_vectors_
w = clf.coef_[0] 
b = clf.intercept_[0]
print([w.dot(X0[i])+b for i in range(len(X0))]) # negative class
print([w.dot(X1[i])+b for i in range(len(X1))]) # positive class
```

Comment: You are asking a question about the fundamentals of svm, but you are using a bit of python that makes it look like a programming question.  I don't think this should be closed.  Can you plot the convergence (classification error, or Cohens kappa) of the fitted classification function as a function of iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, most SVM implementations are soft-margin SVM, which allows a point to be within the margin, or even on the wrong side of the decision boundary, even if the data is linearly separable. However, there is a penalty associated with each point which violates the traditional SVM constraints.

If we set the coefficient on the penalty to some very large value, we get something closer to hard-margin SVM which does what you'd expect:

```
>>> clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 10000.)
>>> clf.fit(X, Y)
>>> w = clf.coef_[0] 
>>> b = clf.intercept_[0]
>>> print([w.dot(X0[i])+b for i in range(len(X0))]) # negative class
[-2.9999999999999987, -0.9999999999999987, -0.9999999999999991, -1.1999999999999988]
>>> print([w.dot(X1[i])+b for i in range(len(X1))]) # positive class
[5.000000000000002, 1.0000000000000004, 1.0000000000000009]
```

As you can see, the margins are now equal on both sides.

Comment: Hi @shimao, thanks for your answer! I tried your C=10000, but it returned hyperplane values `w [2. 2. 0.] b -2.9999999999999987` which is equates to `inf*x + inf*y + 0*z = -3`, so that doesn't help with respect to the hyperplane. So I tried C=2, and then values make more sense :)

Comment: @tamtam $2x+2y+0z = -3$ is a perfectly valid hyperplane